# ASUS TUF Gaming VG249Q1A Color Issues

Tags: colors, calibration

Seeking help with washed-out and dull colors on my ASUS TUF Gaming VG249Q1A monitor. Colors appear less saturated and have a yellow tint compared to other displays.

Tried various troubleshooting steps without success.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image sample]

Comment: Well, you've tagged this 'calibration' - that's what it needs. Really, the only hope of getting similar colours across three displays is a hardware colorimeter. Right now… you don't have a match between any two of those… nor do you know which is correct. I'd suspect all three are out, unless you know that apple lower right was actually blue or purple… because it is on all three screens. It just proves you can't trust your eyes in things like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzIh0.png [Equally, you can't trust the camera that took the photo ;)

Comment: I find that the phone and the laptop's screen have better representation of colors, I want the ASUS monitor look like them

Comment: You don't mean 'better' you mean 'nicer'. Honestly, they're either all out or you have a purple apple. You can try manual calibration, but it really doesn't work, because the parameter set to adjust properly is so large you haven't a hope. You need a colorimeter.